# PowerShell Start-Service Runs Endlessly

Tags: powershell, timeout

#### Problem

So I have a block of code meant to start a service and have the service time out if it takes too long and works fine for the most part. Unfortunately, when this service attempts to start a service that cannot be started, it will display the following Warning Message:

```
WARNING: Waiting for 'ServiceName <ServiceName>' to start...
```

This message will display once every 1-2 seconds, but the time-out never occurs and the Start-Service action seems to continue endlessly. I can safely verify that it will at least continue for 30 minutes (before I manually killed the action).

The code is as follows:

```
Start-Service $ServiceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$results = Wait-ServiceState -ServiceName $ServiceName -ServiceState 'Running' -SecondsToWait $SecondsToWait

Function Wait-ServiceState {
    Param (...)
    Process {
        Try {
            $check = Get-Service $ServiceName
            $timeout = New-TimeSpan -Seconds $SecondsToWait

            $check.WaitForStatus($ServiceState, $timeout.ToString())

            If ($check.Status -ne $ServiceState) { return $False }
            Else { return $true }
        }
        Catch {
            # do nothing: handled by an upper level function
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested the above function against a couple other services and it appears to work fine. I have also successfully used it with `Stop-Service` with absolutely zero issues. I have been searching through threads all morning and have not been able to find anything even remotely similar. I do not know what I am missing...

#### Question

Does anyone have an idea on why it isn't timing out like its supposed to? Perhaps even know how to resolve this?

Comment: I've a similar function but haven't used a Timespan object, just a string: `WaitForStatus($ServiceState, '00:00:30')`

Comment: @JamesC. : I have done both. Using the Timespan object, I have been able to convert different wait times to the same output style of '00:00:30'. I haven't noticed any difference between using either, other than the flexibility.

Comment: Does `WaitForStatus()` still never end if you run the code without the logic?  In other words, run `$s = Get-Service $ServiceName; $t = New-TimeSpan -Seconds 3; $s.WaitForStatus([System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Running, $t)` from the PowerShell command line.

Comment: @BaconBits I think the problem is that it never hits the `WaitForStatus` line. I have tested the function above with the same format as above but for `Stop-Service` and it will hit the 'WaitForStatus' and timeout as expected (if there is a problem). But it is not the same for `Start-Service` . It seems that it never leaves the `Start-Service` line when encountering a service that can't start... and I don't know why

Comment: Well, first I'd put in some `Write-Host "Some text"` lines to the script find out *where* the script is actually hanging.  If it's truly `Start-Service` that's hanging, then I'd try `$s = Get-Service $ServiceName; $s.Start()` to see if that also hangs.  I mean, does *anything* start the service?  Does it actually start?

Comment: @BaconBits I have tried that and it never seems to go past the `Start-Service` line. No I haven't tried the second suggestion, I'll go try that now. As for the last part, even running as admin that service cannot be started manually. Since it is a dead service, I have been using it as a control for various tests, but this issue has me stumped as to why it would fail like this...

Comment: Would you be aginst dropping the whole thing in another thread and running it with a timeout?

Comment: @ArcSet No I wouldn't be against that; however, using the approach suggested by @BaconBits ( `$s = Get-Service $ServiceName; $s.Start()` ) seems to have done the trick for getting it to stop hanging on `Start-Service`

Comment: why would you start the service?....isnt this function for checking if its started?

Comment: @ArcSet : Ah not quite. The problem wasn't the timeout itself, it was the fact that the application was never reaching the timeout code. The program is supposed to attempt to restart the service after updating files, but if the service doesn't start within a set amount of time, its supposed to return `$false` so that the function that made the call to it knows that it timed out. The part you are not seeing is that should it time out, kill the process so that it isn't lingering it a half started state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shout out to @BaconBits for his suggestion:

By converting the following line:

```
Start-Service $ServiceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

To:

```
$s = Get-Service $ServiceName
$s.Start()
```

The application stops hanging on the `Start-Service` line and successfully advances to the WaitForStatus line and everything processes the way I expect it to, regardless of whether the start is successful or not.

However, it seems that the use of one over the other vastly depends on whether you are running in Administrative mode or not.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to start a service and wait for a specified amount of time for it to start. It returns 0 if the service started successfully, or an error code if 1) the service doesn't exist, 2) the service is already running, or 3) the code timed out waiting for the service to start.

```
$ERROR_SERVICE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 1053
$ERROR_SERVICE_ALREADY_RUNNING = 1056
$ERROR_SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST  = 1060

function Start-Service {
  param(
    [String] $serviceName,
    [Int32] $timeoutSeconds
  )
  $service = Get-Service $serviceName
  if ( -not $service ) {
    return $ERROR_SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST
  }
  if ( $service.Status -eq [ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Running ) {
    return $ERROR_SERVICE_ALREADY_RUNNING
  }
  $timeSpan = New-Object Timespan 0,0,$timeoutSeconds
  try {
    $service.Start()
    $service.WaitForStatus([ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Running, $timeSpan)
    return 0
  }
  catch [Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException],[ServiceProcess.TimeoutException] {
    return $ERROR_SERVICE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me after trying everything else:

First, make sure the service isn't 'disabled'.  It appears that Microsoft has introduced some increased permissions to be able to start a disabled service, when it used to work just fine.  Change it to Automatic or Manual like this:

```
get-service <ServiceName> | set-service StartupType <Automatic or Manual>
```

Then run the start command this way:

```
get-service <ServiceName> | start-service -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
```

Notice that isn't -ErrorAction, which I've used many times, but -WarningAction, which I never thought I would even need to use.

The command runs quietly and returns to the prompt.  None of those annoying WARNING: messages.