# Powershell timeout for Start-Service

Tags: powershell

I have a script that, when it reaches a certain point, starts a windows service using `Start-Service`. However, I am having a problem where that service has a certain dependency and so does not start if those conditions are not met. When that happens, the service just gets stuck on "Starting" and the Powershell script does not proceed further. I would like for it to have a timeout of sorts so that if the Windows Service is not started in, for example 20 seconds, it should just move on. If not then just anything simple enough so that the Powershell script does not end up freezing.

My code looks like this:

```
function Starting-Services($ServiceName) {
    if (!($null -eq $(Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $ServiceName }))) {
        "Starting " + $ServiceName + "..."
        Start-Service -Name $ServiceName
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell Start-Service Runs Endlessly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46565897/powershell-start-service-runs-endlessly)

Comment: I made use of `Jobs` with a timer of 30 seconds and that prevents me from getting stuck in `Start-Service`. However, if a service is stuck on `Starting` it just stays like that unless I manually kill the process with its PID